# Outliers of a column of a data frame R

Tags: r, replace, null, outliers, quantile

I am trying to remove outliers (replace by NA) of an specific column of a data set in r:

```
dat2 <- read.csv("~/Rutas Grises/dat2.csv")
```

This is the column summary, it has NAs: `summary(dat2$pct_desti_unicos_sms)`

```
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max.     NA's 
  0.2632   0.5587   1.0470   8.4050   2.5640 100.0000      673
```

Defining the threshold: `f<-quantile(dat2$pct_desti_unicos_sms,3/4,na.rm = T)*1.5`

How I am trying to remove the outliers

```
ifelse(test = !is.na(dat2$pct_desti_unicos_sms) & dat2$pct_desti_unicos_sms > f,
       yes = pct_desti_unicos_sms <- NA,
       no = pct_desti_unicos_sms <- dat2$pct_desti_unicos_sms)
```

But everything it transformed to `NA` or `NAN`:

```
dat2$pct_desti_unicos_sms<-as.numeric(dat2$pct_desti_unicos_sms)
summary(dat2$pct_desti_unicos_sms)


Min.   1st Qu.  Median  Mean 3rd   Qu.    Max.    NA's 
  NA      NA      NA     NaN       NA      NA    1911
```

Comment: We don't know what `dat2$pct_desti_unicos_sms` looks like

Comment: Your syntax is wrong for `ifelse`. It should be `pct_desti_unicos_sms <- ifelse(!is.na(dat2$pct_desti_unicos_sms) & dat2$pct_desti_unicos_sms > f, NA, dat2$pct_desti_unicos_sms)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the `ifelse()`

The final result will be 1 of 2 possibilities, that you should pass to the variable with `<-`, the best way of doing it (in my opinion) is like this:

```
dat2$pct_desti_unicos_sms <- ifelse(
  test = !is.na(dat2$pct_desti_unicos_sms) & dat2$pct_desti_unicos_sms > f,
  yes = NA,
  no = dat2$pct_desti_unicos_sms)
```

---

But, if you want to keep the way you did, you need to write that `pct_desti_unicos_sms` is a column from `dat2`with the `$` operator, otherwise it will create a new vector called `pct_desti_unicos_sms`. Do like this:

```
ifelse(test = !is.na(dat2$pct_desti_unicos_sms) & dat2$pct_desti_unicos_sms > f,
       yes = dat2$pct_desti_unicos_sms <- NA,
       no = dat2$pct_desti_unicos_sms <- dat2$pct_desti_unicos_sms)
```

---

Also, hence your `no` condition in ifelse doesn't affect anything, you can simply work with just a `if()`:

```
if(!is.na(dat2$pct_desti_unicos_sms) & dat2$pct_desti_unicos_sms > f) {
  dat2$pct_desti_unicos_sms <- NA
}
```